# Subscription Expiry Date if user changes dates

Tags: iphone

Our app uses Non-Renewable Subscriptions to provide access to content for one year. The subscription receipt is stored on iCloud (when available) and in the device keychain. There is also a WS that is called on occasion to validate the receipt but does not record the transaction.

Our problem is if the users change their clock backwards (say set the date to 2010), our subscription does not expire after one year but now three years (2013-2010).

Our solution was to say that subscriptions with a duration of more than one year are fraudulent and the receipt is cleared and life goes on.

However, my boss now is complaining about users that set the clock to six months in the past (less than one year so ok, but the subscription lasts for 1.5 years instead of the valid one year).

Is there a better way to be dealing with device clock tampering or is it something we have to live with (as I believe)?

Comment: I guess that you could always check the time using a trusted source (one of the available ntp libraries should prove useful for that). Someone else may have a better idea though.

Comment: ntp was a solution we didn't consider

Comment: This in fact leads me to the question, why can a user edit their device time?

Comment: Probably because they could be out of network communication for long periods of time and need to be able to adjust it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment above,  I would check the time with a trusted server instead of using the local time.  Just as important, once a receipt expires, immediately delete it or mark it as expired so that they can't turn off network access and roll back the time in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If your app gets content from a server then you could store a list of "device-identifiers" combined with an expiration date.

Being on your server the client-time will have no voice on when the subscription is expired or not.

Comment: Or the server could save the receipt like it is suppose to. But the server is out of our control I'm afraid

Comment: In the really worst scenario you can always set up a subscription server which only performs this kind of authentication, placed in the middle between app user and content server...